# How to manage Service Meshes via Infrastructure as Code?

Tags: kubernetes, helm, infrastructure-as-code, kubernetes-helm, istio

In our environment we have found infrastructure as code with YAMLs to be a relatively painless great experience using GIT and source control to commit YAMLs that then get deployed to various environments with a little parameterization (Azure DevOps if it matters).

I have had a strong desire to implement a service mesh solution, but I'm having trouble consolidating "Infrastructure as Code" with a service mesh (Istio would potentially be ideal).

Generally with IAAC I try to keep to the idea that we could move providers and still use most of the same base configurations and yamls. It's also *really* nice when we can isolate as much of the setup as possible into namespaces for development environments and workflows.

However, something like Istio I've had some difficulty grappling with. It seems as though the recommended approach is using Helm. And with the Istio install are dependency requirements like Prometheus.

I've refined down a few possible solutions, and had limited success in attempting the first.

1. Generate YAML from the Helm install and fall leverage existing process. Accept the fact that cluster wide operators are needed and cannot be namespace isolated. Accept any limitations of generated yaml over direct helm install.
2. Enhance our IaaC processes to allow declarative Helm specifications (Add Helm support to our IaaC).
3. Drop the IaaC principles for the helm install and do in-place management.

Is there a mature solution for managing Service Meshes (or Helm packages) via IaaC in as portable of a way as possible? Is there a "standard" appropriate approach to this problem?